# How to access the last column of pandas after doing groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am using Pandas to read an excel file of a factory containing the time of an event, and I group-by the data according to the 'Process','Issue','Cause of issue' columns and the the duration of the event which is a time, I do that like this :

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('taha.xlsx',sheet_name='Data (2)')

def diff_avg(x):
 d = x.diff(periods = -1).mean()
 if d is not pd.NaT:
    return d
 else:
    return '_'


gdata = data.groupby(['Process','Issue','Cause of issue']).agg({

'Duration of maintenance intervention': ['mean','std', 'min', 'max', 'sum','count'],
'Record Date':diff_avg


})
gdata
```

now I have a table, in which data are grouped and at the last column I have a duration of the event, so far so good
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXkid.png)
but the problem is I want to calculate the time between and event up to the next one... so later for each group, I can calculate the average of this time between the events. for that I know I should subtract each duration with the previous one, and have the time between two events, and continue doing it for each group so I can calculate the average. How can I do that?

I have uploaded the data if you want to take a look at the data itself
https://gofile.io/?c=0fAav5

Comment: try to add some example data and what your expected output is, this make your question more clear so people can see through your data what you want.

Comment: Please show your data ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). So you want to do intergroup arithmetic on the result. You can apply `.diff()` on the summarized results (assuming your date/datetime field is a datetime, not a string). This is a duplicate of many existing question.